# How to add BottomAppBar

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I add BottomAppBar to my Main_Activity layout
like this one : [image]

I am using content_main xml in activity_main xml
include layout="@layout/content_main"
only need 2 icon 1-home & 2-download

i tried lots methods but still not working all makes the app crashing

Thanks lots

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.free.music.downloader.activity.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_search_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <include layout="@layout/activity_download" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_play"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="gone">
    <include layout="@layout/ll_play_music" />
</LinearLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorBlue"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_option"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/menu"
            app:tint="@color/colorWhite" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_download_intent"
            style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Music Downloader"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_downloaded"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/music_library" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorBlue">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_search_song"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_ll_download"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/edt_link"
                style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:hint="@string/hint_search"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_search_ic"
                app:tint="@color/colorBlue" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/hot_songs"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textStyle="bold">
                </TextView>
                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/lv_hot_songs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
            </LinearLayout>



            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                app:adSize="BANNER"
                app:adUnitId="@string/ads_banner">
            </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/het_key"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textStyle="bold">

                </TextView>
                <include layout="@layout/item_sugesstion_tag" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  View.OnClickListener, AdapterMusicSearch.ClickCallBack {
private Random random;
private final String[] PERMISSION_LIST = {
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};
private ArrayList<String> arrKey = new ArrayList<>();

public static final String HOT_SONGS_TITLE = "HOT_SONGS_TITLE";
public static final String HOT_SONGS_ID = "HOT_SONGS_ID";
public static final String CHECK_FIRST = "checkFirst";
private TextView tvDownloadIntent;
private AdapterMusicSearch adapterMusicSearch;
private ArrayList<Song> arrHotSongs = new ArrayList<>();
private SharedPreferences checkFirst;
private ImageView imgDownloaded, imgOption;
private ImageView imgPlayAndPause;
private RelativeLayout rlSearch;
private RecyclerView lvHotSongs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    if (!checkPermissionAvailable()) {
        return;
    }
    initViews();
}

private boolean checkPermissionAvailable() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        for (String p : PERMISSION_LIST) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(p) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(PERMISSION_LIST, 0);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (checkPermissionAvailable()) {
        initViews();
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}

public String randomKey() {
    return this.arrKey.get(new Random().nextInt(this.arrKey.size()));
}

public void initViews() {
    addKeyYoutube();

    checkFirst = getSharedPreferences(CHECK_FIRST, MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (checkFirst.getString(CHECK_FIRST, "").equals("") || checkFirst.getString(CHECK_FIRST, "") == null) {
        checkFirst.edit().putString(CHECK_FIRST, "1").commit();
    } else if (checkFirst.getString(CHECK_FIRST, "").equals("1")) {
        random = new Random();
        int x = random.nextInt(3);
        Log.e("asdfasdfa", x + "");
        if (x == 1) {
            showDialogRating();
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("asdfadfadf", checkFirst.getString(CHECK_FIRST, ""));
    }
    rlSearch = findViewById(R.id.rl_search_song);
    rlSearch.setOnClickListener(this);
    imgPlayAndPause = findViewById(R.id.img_play_and_pause);
    imgPlayAndPause.setOnClickListener(this);
    imgDownloaded = findViewById(R.id.img_downloaded);
    imgOption = findViewById(R.id.img_option);
    imgOption.setOnClickListener(this);
    imgDownloaded.setOnClickListener(this);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(DownloadedActivity.UPDATE_MUSIC);
    tvDownloadIntent = findViewById(R.id.tv_download_intent);
    tvDownloadIntent.setOnClickListener(this);
    lvHotSongs = findViewById(R.id.lv_hot_songs);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManagerHotSongs = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManagerHotSongs.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    lvHotSongs.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerHotSongs);
    adapterMusicSearch = new AdapterMusicSearch(arrHotSongs, this);
    adapterMusicSearch.setCallBack(this);
    lvHotSongs.setAdapter(adapterMusicSearch);
    loadHotSongs();

}


public void onClickTag(View view) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) view;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DownloadActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("KEY_TAG", textView.getText());
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.rl_search_song:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, DownloadActivity.class));

            break;

        case R.id.img_downloaded:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, DownloadedActivity.class));
            break;
        case R.id.img_option:
            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, imgOption);
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_option);
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.menu_share:
                            shareApp();
                            return true;
                        case R.id.menu_rate:
                            rateApp();
                            return true;
                        default:
                            return false;
                    }

                }
            });
            popupMenu.show();
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }
}

private void rateApp() {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName());
    Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
    try {
        startActivity(goToMarket);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName())));
    }
}

private void shareApp() {
    try {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My application name");
        String shareMessage = "\nLet me recommend you this application\n\n";
        shareMessage = shareMessage + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "\n\n";
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareMessage);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "choose one"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "share app error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void showDialogRating() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_rating_app);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.show();
    Button btnCancel = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel_rating);
    Button btnOkRating = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok_rating);
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    btnOkRating.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkFirst.edit().putString(CHECK_FIRST, "2").commit();
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName());
            Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

            goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
            try {
                startActivity(goToMarket);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName())));
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}


public void loadHotSongs() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    JsonGetDataByRetrofit jsonGetData = retrofit.create(JsonGetDataByRetrofit.class);
    try {
        Call<Example> call = jsonGetData.getHotSongs(randomKey());
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
                try {
                    if (response.body().getItems() != null) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getItems().size(); i++) {
                            String category = response.body().getItems().get(i).getSnippet().getCategoryId();
                            if (category.equals("10")) {
                                String id = response.body().getItems().get(i).getId();
                                String title = response.body().getItems().get(i).getSnippet().getTitle();
                                String auth = response.body().getItems().get(i).getSnippet().getChannelTitle();
                                String linkImage = "";
                                linkImage = response.body().getItems().get(i).getSnippet().getThumbnails().getMedium().getUrl();
                                if (!id.contains("-")) {
                                    arrHotSongs.add(new Song(id, title, auth, linkImage));
                                }
                                adapterMusicSearch.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("error", "error get hot songs");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure
                    (Call<Example> call, Throwable
                            t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this
                        , "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        call.clone();
    } catch (
            Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "please wait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void clickItem(int position) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DownloadActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(HOT_SONGS_ID, arrHotSongs.get(position).getIdMusic());
    intent.putExtra(HOT_SONGS_TITLE, arrHotSongs.get(position).getTitle());
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void clickItemDownload(int position) {

}
```

Comment: https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation/android

Answer (score 1):

You first need to define a `res/menu/my_navigation_items.xml` for your items in your bottom nav bar

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="@string/menu_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_search" />
     <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/menu_settings"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_add" />
     <item android:id="@+id/action_navigation"
          android:title="@string/menu_navigation"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_menu" />
 </menu>
```

Then you add a `BottomNavigationView` in your xml adding as an `app:menu` your menu created previously

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schema.android.com/apk/res/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/navigation"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="56dp"
     android:layout_gravity="start"
     app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />
```

Then to navigate between the items you should use `BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id. action_search:
                    //showYourFragmentForActionSearch

                case R.id. action_settings:
                    //showYourFragmentForActionSettings

                case R.id. action_navigation:
                    //showYourFragmentForActionNavigation
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Then you set this `BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` to your `BottomNavigationView` created previously in the layout

```
BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
```

With this you could have an idea how to work with `BottomNavigationView` if you want more details feel free to check this [`BottomNavViewsWithFragments`](https://github.com/bukunmialuko/BottomNavViewWithFragments) repository.

Comment: i tried this didn't work :(
is there any other way ?
thanks

Comment: What do you mean didn't work? What have you tried?